# RegEx to split string 'DB415.DBD21.3'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a parameter (received as a string) to be able to use the values to perform certain operation. For example, the string would be:

```
DB415.DBX12.3
```

I would require it to be split as:

1. DB: Non numeric character (s) at the beginning - Split using RegEx `/(?:^[A-Z]+)/`
2. 415: Numeric character (s) - Split using RegEx `/^(?![A-Z]+)(?:\d+)/`
3. DBX: Non numeric character (s) - Can't seem to get this right, tried `/^(?!^[A-Z]+)(?!\d+)(?!\.)(?:[A-Z]+)/`
4. 12: Numeric character (s)
5. 3: Numeric characters (s)

Any help with 3, 4 and 5 would be very helpful!

EDIT: This is for Javascript, and ideally, I would like to get those 5 parameters in an array.

Comment: Why splitting? Try [`^(\D*)(\d+)\.(\D*)(\d+)\.(\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/gL3jH2/1) and access the captured groups. Or do you need a splitting one by all means?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Hi, sorry, this is meant to be in Javascript. Edited the question.

Comment: Then my suggestion is valid, posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a *matching* regex for that:

```
/^(\D*)(\d+)\.(\D*)(\d+)\.(\d+)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gL3jH2/1)

I just follow your logic, and the regex matches all the steps you enumerated.

JS demo:

```js
var re = /^(\D*)(\d+)\.(\D*)(\d+)\.(\d+)$/; 
var str = 'DB415.DBX12.3';
var res = str.match(re);
if (res) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
}
```

Comments on the regex:

- `\D` matches any character but a digit
- `\d` matches  any digit
- `\D*` matches zero or more digits (if there must be at least one, replace with `\D+`)
- `\.` matches a literal dot. If there can be more than a dot, say, a hyphen, you will need to replace with a character class like `[.-]` keeping the hyphen at the end.

Comment: The values you need are in the form of an array, from Index 1 to Index 5. `res[1]` = `DB`, etc. You may initialize the values inside a loop with `RegExp#exec()`, too. The choice is yours.

Comment: You can use `res.slice(1)` to get the captured groups just like `exec` with loop

Comment: Yes, that can be also quite handy here, thanks for a hint.